# How to configure BOSH over XMPP in tigase?

Tags: tigase

I have installed tigase XMPP server. Now I wanted to configure BOSH in order to connect through http. I am pretty much new to this environment. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

BOSH is activated by default. Thus, you can edit its default configuration by editing the `init.properties` file in the `etc/` folder:

```
bosh/connections/ports[i] = 5280, 5281
bosh/connections/5281/socket = ssl
bosh/connections/5281/type = accept
```

5280 is the default non-encrypted port and 5281 is the default encrypted port for BOSH. You can edit both ports to your conveniance. Then, you will be able to connect to `http://yourdomain.com/http-bind` and `https://yourdomain.com/http-bind` depending on which you want to use.

By the way, I recommend using the last release version of Tigase (and avoiding beta versions). You can find it [here](https://projects.tigase.org/projects/tigase-server/files).

Answer (score 1):

What version of the Tigase XMPP Server do you use? In all recent versions Bosh is active by default and does not require any extra configuration.

Comment: Hi Artur, I am using tigase-server-5.1.0-beta4-b2836, Currently I have installed apache2.2 and it redirects each request with http-bind to tigase_server:5280, please correct me If I missed anything. Regards Anup